# Failed to be authorized from yarn resource manager webapp under kerberos

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, hadoop-yarn, unauthorized, webui

The authorized failure is happened when accessing yarn resource manager web UI by chrome browser with kerberos spnego (yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address:8088/cluster).

The failure is shown like:

```
     "HTTP ERROR 403 Problem accessing /cluster. Reason: GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Request is a replay (34))"
```

PS. It is successfully to access others (namenode, jobhistory etc) web UI, but yarn resource manager by chrome browser with kerberos spnego

Hadoop is 2.5.2

May someone help me to check this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be resolved by setting :

"yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.delegation-token-auth-filter.enabled=false"

in yarn-site.xml of Hadoop-2.5.2

The YARNAuthenticationFilter  can be ignored by "false" value from the webapp default request filter chain: chain=NoCacheFilter->NoCacheFilter->safety->YARNAuthenticationFilter->authentication->guice->default

TO the one as: chain=NoCacheFilter->NoCacheFilter->safety->authentication->guice->default

Answer (score 0):

Usually you get this when working with a kerberized cluster installation when you have not instructed your browser to use Kerberos authentication connecting to some domains - this is needed for some Hadoop webapps.

For Chrome on OSX for example just type into your console:

`defaults write com.google.Chrome AuthServerWhitelist "*.domain.realm"`

`defaults write com.google.Chrome AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist  "*.domain.realm"`

where `domain.realm` is the `[domain_realm]` entry from your Kerberos configuration file `/etc/krb5.conf`.